# Can't add reference from C# PCL project to F# PCL project as project reference

Tags: c#, f#, xamarin.forms

I wanna add project reference from Xamarin.Forms PCL C# project to F# PCL project, but Visual Studio15 shows alert as "Unable to add a reference to project 'PortableLibrary2'.
 Portable Library projects can only reference other Portable Library projects and assemblies." If I use Visual Studio13,it shows "Unable to add a reference to project 'PortableLibrary2'." then 'The method or operation is not implemented.'.

I attached link to [sample project on github](https://github.com/omanuke/TestPCL)
I created this sample with following steps
1.create F# PCL project named "PortableLibrary2" as profile7
2.create C# Xamarin.Forms blank pcl project named "App1".
3.change profile from App1 project property to profile7

Before I created similar project structure and it could add project reference properly. I can't find difference which makes these different results.

adding reference to compiled PortableLibrary2.dll by Browse works fine properly.

Any idea?

Comment: I added C# PCL Library 'Class Library1'.
I can't add reference from 'Class Library1' to F# PCL Lib too.

Comment: Seems like this is same problem as [Cannot add reference from C# PCL to F# PCL (VS 2015 Update 1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34828235/cannot-add-reference-from-c-sharp-pcl-to-f-pcl-vs-2015-update-1?rq=1)

Comment: I tried this from VS2013 Update4. I can add project reference successfully. This may be VS's bug.

Comment: If it's indeed just a VS bug, you can always edit the fsproj/csproj files by hand to add the problematic reference.

Comment: When I edit csproj by hand,VS shows warning yellow triangle in References and warn message "unable to add reference..." appears on Error List.

Comment: I can add project reference successfully on another machine with Visual Studio 2013 Update5.
This means my main machine's VS has some installation problem? If it's true how can I fix it? from repair menu of installer?